# Docker execute ant script after tomcat starts?

Tags: tomcat, ant, docker

Dockerfile works correctly for tomcat. After tomcat starts, I have to trigger ant scripts. catalina.sh is started from a separate run.sh file. So, Dockerfile has
CMD ["/tmp/run.sh"]

The run.sh file has below lines:

- catalina.sh run
- antscript

Tomcat starts but ant scripts are not called. I also tried other possibilities like:

- catalina.sh run && antscripts

tomcat starts but antscripts are not triggered

Is there a way that I can call the ant scripts automatically after tomcat starts? I dont want to run the scripts afterwards by using docker exec.

Comment: The reason your antscript does not executed is because you catalina.sh never completes. With docker the tomcat process is in foreground and antscript is not executed.

Comment: One of the ways, I can think of achieving the functionality is by starting antscripts with nohup command before catalina.sh, and add a delay in antscript (use a wrapper shell script with sleep command). The delay can be simple time based wait, or could just watch tomcat logs till server startup is complete to start execution.

Comment: using nohup command to run a wrapper script worked for me. Thanks

Comment: cool. I am making it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways, I can think of achieving the functionality is

- Starting antscripts with nohup command before catalina.sh,
- and adding a delay in antscript (use a wrapper shell script with sleep command).

The delay can be simple time based wait, or could just watch tomcat logs till server startup is complete to start execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can write you commands next way:

```
catalina.sh run & (sleep 20 && antscripts)
```

It will call antscripts in 20 seconds after catalina execution start. You can change time for estimated time of tomcat start.

Also you can wait for open some tcp port:

```
catalina.sh run & ((while ! echo exit | nc localhost 8080; do sleep 10; done) && antscripts)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using & after catalina.sh run. I can trigger a script that would wait for tomcat to start and then execute the antscripts.

Comment: However, the problem is that the docker container exits after the script ends.