# Run commands after docker tomcat startup

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, server, docker-compose

I would like when running a docker container with a Java application (spring or legacy applications), when finishes tomcat startup, run a script that plays a sound *(which would serve as a notification)*.

The problem is know how run commands triggered after Tomcat startup.

Comment: As a general rule, "plays a sound" or otherwise interacting with the host's hardware devices isn't something you can do from a container.  You might try one of the techniques in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) (the approaches using `nc` or `wait-for-it` aren't Docker-specific) to run this from the host.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a [script waiting for Tomcat to be fully ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49049425/6309)

```sh
until [ 
  "$(curl -w '%{response_code}' --no-keepalive -o /dev/null --connect-timeout 1 
          -u USERNAME:PASSWORD http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list)" == "200"];
```

So your Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` could be launching `catalina.sh && yourScript`.

Or, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37460717/6309), launching your script with nohup command before calling `catalina.sh`.

The idea remain: your script will loop until it detects Tomcat is ready.